# Keeping the design of 2 tables in sync

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

The problem:

I have 2 tables in a database:

```
TableA               TableB
X, Y, Z              X, Y, Z
```

If I add column W to table A I want to copy it automatically to Table B with the same name and data type (without writing it explicitly).

Constraints on deployment:

The tables are updated using update scripts (so must be able to be called / executed in tsql).
There are multiple tables that could be updated (however I can hand code a mapping if needed)

Example update script:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.COLUMNS C INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES T ON C.OBJECT_ID = T.OBJECT_ID
                WHERE C.NAME = 'W' AND T.NAME = 'TableA')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE TableA ADD W [Int] NULL
END
GO
```

At the end of this script I want to add my ‘SyncMyTables’ SQL

So far from my research I have found 3 possible ways to tackle this:

1. Call a function at the end of the script which syncs the table designs
2. Some form of table trigger (but I don’t think triggers are that clever)
3. Some inline sql that builds up an update string and then runs it against the database.

Option 1 seems the most sensible to me.

**What help I need:**

Some guidance on how best to tackle this.

An example to point me in the right direction.

Cheers

please note, I don't want to keep the content of the columns in sync, I need to keep the table DESIGN

Comment: Why can't you simply run the alter statement for both tables? The amount of work required to dynamically do this will outweigh the incredibly insignificant amount of effort to change a table name in a thousand alter scripts. What you are doing requires dynamic sql with a LOT of complexity to make sure you are 100% correct in every situation. Not a small feat.

Comment: I'm with @SeanLange on this one. Alternatively you could modify your schema and get rid of one of these 2 tables and add a discriminator column to the remaining table and merge the content. If you want the readers to be unaware of the discriminator then create 2 SQL views that do nothing more than return the data minus discriminator.

Comment: You can use Microsoft Sync Framework where you can set the scope_config and scope_definition to set of tables to sync between the tables from different servers.

Comment: At sean and igor thanks for taking the time to reply, I really appreciate it!  The reason I can't write the alter myself is that multiple developers will be updating these scripts, and may not be aware it needs to be done, therefore I want to remove the human risk of error by automating it.   The reason I need both tables is  tableB serves as a historic record of the values that were in tableA at a single point in time, so want it to be queryable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column duplication can be achieved with a DDL trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DDL_TableA_TableB
    ON database
    FOR  ALTER_TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @CommandText nvarchar(1000)
    SELECT @CommandText = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','SYSNAME');
    if left(@CommandText, 26) = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA ADD'
    begin
        set @CommandText =  replace( @CommandText, 'TableA', 'TableB')
        exec sp_executesql @CommandText
    end
end
```

Comment: This looks like the kind of solution I was after, thank you I'll give it a try on Monday!